# Segmentation fault when run old debian containers if docker host is debian10(buster)

Tags: docker, debian

When I run old *debian gnu/linux* images (v6 "squeeze", v7 "wheezy") on a new system (v10 "buster"), I get an error (f.e., with *bash*):

```
$ docker run --rm -ti debian:6 sh
# bash
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
# exit
$ docker run --rm -ti debian:7 sh
# bash
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
# exit
```

How to fix it?

Comment: [same question in russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1020602/178576)

Comment: If you want to run some containers under different operating systems then you'll need to employ proper virtualization rather than application isolation such as docker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to have a look for [this discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34301) & also [this](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/58#issuecomment-315150740).

From above discusstion we could see it's due to a kernel configuration change in debian10, specifying next configure in `/etc/default/grub` to fix it:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vsyscall=emulate"
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `update-grub` before rebooting after this.